# использование copy в postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, postgresql

Есть таблица mydocs с колонками ( id serial, docform int, content text) делаю такой запрос

```
copy (select (content) from mydocs where id=30 ) to 'D:/html/ex10.xml' ;
```

выбираю один файл с id=30 и кладу его в существующий или в новый файл в папке пути, всё работает но

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
\r\n
<tutorial>
\r\n
<title>&quot;Заметки об XSL&quot;</title>
\r\n
<author>лермонтов</author>
\r\n
</tutorial>
```

В версии документа, который помещается в файл присутствуют \r и \n, как я понимаю это форматирование, так вот как от него избавиться, или как найти функцию, которая будет по человечески класть xml в файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
copy (select (replace(content, e'\r\n', '')) from mydocs where id=30 ) to 'c:/data/ex10.xml';
```

Вроде работает